# How to solve a replacement SIM coming up as “SIM not provisioned”

Tags: iphone, network, sim

I’ve been given a replacement SIM card by O2 but when I put it into my iPhone I get the message “SIM not provisioned”. I know that it needs to be activated but the advice seems unclear. My brother has tried as well and got the same issue.

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

How do I solve this?

Comment: I can only guess you didn't follow the [SIM swap](https://community.o2.co.uk/t5/How-to-Guides/SIM-Swap-a-mini-guide-incl-eSim/ba-p/1060675) instructions carefully. You need to get in touch with O2 - https://www.o2.co.uk/contactus

Comment: Well, it’s not that simple. The phone was stolen so we’ve got another and a new sim but we’re not in the uk and that’s where it needs to be activated. My brother is the one trying to activate it for us back in the uk

Comment: You're going to need the phone currently containing the SIM capable of actually connecting directly to O2 UK 'over the air'  to be able to do that. You can't do it from 'abroad'. Get him to call O2 & see if there's anything they can do - but I doubt it.